# How to change cursor size in LightDM+GTK

Tags: lightdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter

I am using the GTK greeter for LightDM but the cursor looks very tiny on my laptop's 1080 display. I have already set the DPI setting and some text looks big, but the center input is still small and the cursor remains small, too. I followed some instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:LightDM#Cursor_size_in_lightdm-gtk-greeter)  which advice to use `dconf` as root, but doing:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size 32
```

fails saying that the connection is closed.

Also, I found out that root isn't supposed to use `dconf`. I tried `dconf-editor` with the same results, and `/etc/gtk-3.0` doesn't even exist in my system (Fedora 29). What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

There are basic cursor themes for Xorg except these could be changed by the Fedora or the use of window managers or desktop managers to override Xorg.

In my voidlinux installation there is an "xcursor-themes" package subtitled "Xorg cursor themes" containing the /usr/share/icons/whiteglass directory. Then in my .Xresources file I have this:

```
Xcursor.theme: whiteglass
Xcursor.size: 48px
```

That works good for my 1080p notebook. Fedora or your installation could do things differently. I don't have the dconf or LightDM+GTK installed at all just using the lightweight jwm window manager so your setup might make things more complicated.